# how do I pass variables as arguments to a method via click?

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, methods, click

Hello I am relatively new to click and python and am trying to pass a variable to a method within a class via click. I'm not sure if the click decorators should go above the **init** or above the method itself.

```
import click
import os
from datetime import datetime


class table_update:
    scriptdirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    @click.command()
    @click.option('-tn','--tablename',prompt=True)
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.tablename = self.tablename
       
    # @click.group()
    # @click.command()
    # @click.option('--tn','--tablename',prompt=True)
    def gettime(self,tablename):
        """
        Set up timer and time functions for table update
        """
        print('get_time function running')
        print(f"Class variable ScriptDirectoryname inherited:{self.scriptdirectory}")
        print(f"here's the table: {tablename}")
        global_start = datetime.now()
        # get project path name & set to current path
        changedir= os.chdir(self.scriptdirectory)
        print(changedir)

time = table_update().gettime()
time
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with this...

You need to write:

```
def __init__(self, tablename):
    self.tablename = tablename
```

Put decorators on the method not constructor...

I gotta be honest with you, it is hard for me to understand what is the purpose of this code? What is that you wanna make it do?
If you explain more i can help :)

Comment: hi @TheOriginalOdis, I'm trying to do a simple workflow that sends a table to a db. Each step will be a method and some of the methods will need arguments passed via click.
- Set up timer
- Set up logging
- Set up and send email alert
- create connection to db
- Find index location of table as file on pc
- Truncate table
- send table to db
-execute all methods in order